# Run QEMU from within Eclipse External tools

Tags: eclipse, qemu

I'd like to ask since I am setting up the Eclipse IDE for Yocto app development and I got stuck to start the QEMU from within Eclipse.

I got working QEMU image OK such as

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/work/community/build-x11$ runqemu qemuarm
tmp/deploy/images/qemuarm/zImage-qemuarm.bin
tmp/deploy/images/qemuarm/fsl-image-multimedia-full-qemuarm.ext4
```

Within the Eclipse I follow

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html#oxygen-starting-qemu-in-user-space-nfs-mode

But by configuring "External Tools" and try to run QEMU I got following

```
runqemu - INFO - Running MACHINE=qemuarm bitbake -e...
ERROR: Unable to find conf/bblayers.conf or conf/bitbake.conf. BBAPTH is unset and/or not in a build directory?
runqemu - WARNING - Couldn't run 'bitbake -e' to gather environment information:

runqemu - WARNING - Can't find qemuboot conf file, DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE is NULL!
runqemu - INFO - Running MACHINE=qemuarm bitbake -e...
ERROR: Unable to find conf/bblayers.conf or conf/bitbake.conf. BBAPTH is unset and/or not in a build directory?
runqemu - WARNING - Couldn't run 'bitbake -e' to gather environment information:

runqemu - INFO - Setting STAGING_DIR_NATIVE to OECORE_NATIVE_SYSROOT (/home/ubuntu/work/community/build-x11/tmp/work/armv5e-fslc-linux-gnueabi/meta-ide-support/1.0-r3/recipe-sysroot-native)
runqemu - INFO - Setting STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE to /home/ubuntu/work/community/build-x11/tmp/work/armv5e-fslc-linux-gnueabi/meta-ide-support/1.0-r3/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin
runqemu - INFO - QB_MEM is not set, use 512M by default
runqemu - INFO - Continuing with the following parameters:

KERNEL: [/home/ubuntu/work/community/build-x11/tmp/deploy/images/qemuarm/zImage-qemuarm.bin]
MACHINE: [qemuarm]
FSTYPE: [nfs]
NFS_DIR: [/home/ubuntu/work/community/build-x11/MY_QEMU_ROOTFS]
CONFFILE: []

/bin/sh: 1: stty: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/work/community/sources/poky/scripts/runqemu", line 1270, in main
    config.setup_network()
  File "/home/ubuntu/work/community/sources/poky/scripts/runqemu", line 997, in setup_network
    self.saved_stty = subprocess.check_output("stty -g", shell=True).decode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 708, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'stty -g' returned non-zero exit status 127
Cleanup
Command 'lesspipe' is available in the following places
 * /bin/lesspipe
 * /usr/bin/lesspipe
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
lesspipe: command not found
Command 'dircolors' is available in '/usr/bin/dircolors'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dircolors: command not found
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse$
```

I wonder if any has experience such a problem on setting it up "External Tools" with Eclipse?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the build path and then trigger this command will work. 
  OR
Run source oe-init-build-env build path.